# Is there a library for quaternions and matrices with all the standard operations?

Tags: java, jar, quaternions

is there a java library which can handle quaternions and matrices (quaternion matrix multiplication) with all the standard operations?

(i searched google and here before - but didnt find any adequate solution)

Comment: What searches have you tried; what have you found but is inadequate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Jave3D javax.vecmath](http://java.net/projects/vecmath) package has quaternions support (`Quat4D`) and quite a lot of the most common operations are supported. It also has matrix operations that can be applied to quaternions.

You will probably find that it fits most of your needs - and it should not be too hard to add any additional operations if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

There is also JME3's [Quaternion](http://javadoc.jmonkeyengine.org/com/jme3/math/Quaternion.html). JME3 classes' interface and javadoc is substandard. Also it uses float precision everywhere. I would only use it if performance is an issue, for example in a game.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has Quaternion support in [org.apache.commons.math3.complex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Quaternion.html).
It seems to have the usual required operations.